# What is the proper #include for the function 'sleep()'?

Tags: c, posix, sleep

I am using the Big Nerd Ranch book Objective-C Programming, and it starts out by having us write in C in the first few chapters. In one of my programs it has me create, I use the sleep function. In the book it told me to put `#include <stdlib.h>` under the `#include <stdio.h>` part. This is supposed to get rid of the warning that says "Implicit declaration of function 'sleep' is invalid in C99". But for some reason after I put `#include <stdlib.h>`, the warning does not go away.. This problem does not stop the program from running fine, but I was just curious on which `#include` I needed to use!

Comment: If you use any mayor IDE(NetBeans,IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse). type the name of any function, then Alt+Enter it will auto-import the library that has it.

Comment: @T04435: In C libraries are not imported. The compiler does *not* need them. The linker *might* link them, but only *after* the compiler is *done*. In C the compiler *needs a prototype* of a function to to use a function. Prototypes typically come in *header files* (.h).

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The sleep [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) says it is declared in `<unistd.h>`.

Synopsis:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
```

> **unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);**

Comment: I had not! Thank you! it was just kind of bothering me, because the book said that the <stdlib.h> would get rid of the warning... weird haha @simonc

Comment: Would it be better to use the sleep() function or time() to create a delay?

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn: At least the C function `time()` does **not** created a delay, at least not a well defined delay, based on the arguments passed.

Answer (score 82):

`sleep` is a non-standard function.

- On UNIX, you shall include `<unistd.h>`.
- On MS-Windows, `Sleep` is rather from `<windows.h>`.

In every case, check the documentation.

Comment: w.r.t. the C standard. w.r.t. POSIX, it is

Comment: On UNIX, Sleep is actually usleep and it takes microseconds (milliseconds*1000) instead of seconds.

Comment: Don't use usleep: _"4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001. POSIX.1-2001 declares this function obsolete; use nanosleep(2) instead. POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of usleep()."_ https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

Comment: Windows's `Sleep()` and POSIX' `sleep()` are **not** the same. They take different arguments. For former takes milli-seconds, the latter takes seconds!

Answer (score 74):

this is what I use for a cross-platform code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main()
{
  pollingDelay = 100
  //do stuff

  //sleep:
  #ifdef _WIN32
  Sleep(pollingDelay);
  #else
  usleep(pollingDelay*1000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
  #endif

  //do stuff again
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: usleep() was removed in POSIX.1-2008. Use nanosleep(). https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

Answer (score 16):

> *What is the proper #include for the function 'sleep()'?*

`sleep()` isn't Standard C, but POSIX so it should be:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Answer (score 9):

[`sleep(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/) is in `unistd.h`, not `stdlib.h`.  Type `man 3 sleep` on your command line to confirm for your machine, but I presume you're on a Mac since you're learning Objective-C, and on a Mac, you need `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `sleep` is a non-standard function, I created a `sleep` function with the standard library `time.h`

```
#include <time.h>

void sleep(double s) {
    time_t cur_time = time(NULL);
    while ((difftime(time(NULL), cur_time)) < s);
}
```

Comment: Taking the CPU into a While-Loop is NOT a sleep!. a sleep function is to get the CPU to actually sleep and conserve power, your function does the exact opposite, I hope this makes sense,