# Sleep program execution in C for a few seconds

Tags: c

How can I sleep or pause the program excecution by a few seconds in C? I'm looking for something like this that is used in Java:

```
Thread.sleep(interval);
```

Is possible do this using C ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not really any suitable standard C function. You should use system-specific functions for this. In which case you have to tell us which system you are programming for.

Comment: Yeah - call your OS Sleep() API, whatever that is:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer here: [What is the proper #include for the function 'sleep' in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818084/what-is-the-proper-include-for-the-function-sleep-in-c)

Be careful that it works differently in Unix and Windows, whereas in one is measured in millisecs and in the other in secs.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void){

    sleep(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Read more [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep).

Comment: i'm programming on windows, but thanks a lot.