# getting text to print character by character in C

Tags: c, console-output

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char words[] = "Hello this is text.\n";
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(words); i++) {
        sleep(1);
        putchar(words[i]);
    }
}
```

I've been attempting to have the program output the text slowly, character by character into the console (to look like someone is typing it). However instead when I run this code I get one massive pause, and then it prints the whole string at once. How do I get this to work.

(also no C++ solutions please)

Comment: can u use function usleep, here you can pass arguments in miliseconds instead of seconds. Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818084/what-is-the-proper-include-for-the-function-sleep-in-c

Comment: use [`fflush`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) after putchar

Answer (score 4):

`stdio` is buffered to make it more efficient, writing a single character isn't enough to get it to write it's buffer to the console. You need to flush stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char words[] = "Hello this is text.\n";
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(words); i++) {
        sleep(1);
        putchar(words[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>` in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the standard output is line buffered by default.

Flush the output after each character like this:

```
putchar(words[i]);
fflush(stdout);  //<---
```