# Is there some sort of a command for creating a delay in a program

Tags: c, delay, sleep, usleep

Many people told me there is a better way to create a delay for *X* amount of milliseconds. People told me about sleep command and usleep(), but I failed to make that work.

Currently I'm using this:

```
void delay(unsigned int mseconds) {
    clock_t goal=mseconds+clock();
    while(goal>clock());
}
```

And by doing this

```
delay(500);
printf("Hello there");
```

I can make text appear half a second later, but I want to find a better way to do this since people told me this is a bad method to do it and that it can be not very accurate.

Comment: In which way did your attempts to use sleep() and usleep() not work?

Comment: Are you aware of the meaning of "busy waiting"? It describes the problem caused by your method more accuratly than "not very accurate".

Comment: Pausing execution is not a language feature but typically an operating system primitive.  Most C standard libraries contains a sleep function, but precision and granularity is historically poor.  It would improve your question if you stated *why* you want the program to pause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818084/what-is-the-proper-include-for-the-function-sleep-in-c/14818104

Comment: @wallyk I want to use it to make things appear slowly, basically using `printf("Waiting"); for(i=0;i<3;i++){ printf("."); delay(500)}`

Comment: @Yunnosch basically just by typing them between stuff...

Comment: Is that last comment supposed to answer one of my questions? I do not see a connection.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry didn't read them fully, my bad, basically compiler gave errors that those things don't exist

Comment: Please quote the compiler messages in your question. Do not forget to completly list all of your includes. You probably also want to state your environment; OS, compiler, version, ...

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry to take everyones time, made it work (answer down below).

Answer (score 1):

I figured everything out!!! God I was dump when trying to make `sleep()` command work first time

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(){

    int load;
    int Loadwait=100

    for(load=0;load<100;load+=5){
        printf("Loading %d",load);
        Sleep(Loadwait);
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) you should be able to use [thrd_sleep()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep).

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Time: %s", ctime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
    thrd_sleep(&(struct timespec){.tv_sec=1}, NULL); // sleep 1 sec
    printf("Time: %s", ctime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
}
```

Comment: `threads.h` is optional in `C11` and many don't support it, as POSIX has `pthreads` and Windows has `windows.h`.

At least use `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to check, if it is available.

Comment: It's not really about the compiler, but which `libc` it uses.
For example on most Linuces _glibc_ is used, which sadly doesn't support `threads.h` but _musl_ on the other hand supports it.
It's really a shame the standard made it optional.

tested with clang 6.0.1 / gcc 8.1.1 and glib 2.27 / musl 1.1.19